# What is the proper way to include/exclude Tags Junit5 on Kotlin DSL Gradle

Tags: kotlin, gradle, junit, junit5, gradle-kotlin-dsl

In standard Gradle you can do:

```
test {
    useJUnitPlatform {
        includeTags 'fast'
        excludeTags 'slow'
    }
}
```

I haven't been able to convert it into Kotlin's Gradle DSL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Example syntax for tagging tests is available in the docs [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#test_grouping).

```kotlin
// build.gradle.kts 

tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform {
        includeTags("fast")
        excludeTags("slow")
    }
}
```